# Getting data from javascript console

Tags: javascript, console

[image: That is my web site's console view.]

```
              FB.api(
                    "/1474642229461397/members",
                    function (response) {
                        if (response && !response.error) {
                            /* handle the result */
                            console.log(response);
                            $("#status").text = response.data.lenght;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            window.location = "ClearCache.aspx?error=non-group";
                        }
                    }
                );
```

That is my code snippet for writing those to console.
I want to get that lenght:219 in my javascript codes as a variable.
How can I do that?

Comment: Exactly how you did it.

Comment: which part do you mean? There is a facebook api insertion codes before that. This works with facebook. And I want to get the lenght part of console inside my javascript variable.

Comment: `response.data.length` gets the length. However, `text` is a function, assuming you are using jQuery. Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

Comment: yeah I tried $("#status").text(response.data.lenght); also.. nothing changes :S

Comment: it returns "undefined"

Comment: Oh, you have a typo. It's length, not lenght

Comment: I've read about the .text() function.. it seems I am not gonna use it. I just use it for trying purpose.

.innerText, alert(),.... anything but test

Comment: ahahaha ! Thank you very much :))) You've taught me a new word :))